# Dart Pub serve won't start

Tags: html, ide, dart

so I re-installed all my dev tools on a system and moved my entire project folder into it. I'm getting an error even before I open the dart editor.

when I run Pub Serve in terminal I get a

> bad state: subscribing to a closed stream

or an equally confusing

> Can't find pubspec.yaml

No idea why... since the exact same layout worked on a different machine.

Similarities

- both machines run Windows 7
- both machines have the same version of the Dart SDK and editor
- both machines are 64bit (and are running the appropriate tools)

Differences

- the machine not working is an Intel where the other is an AMD
- the machine not working has all its Windows updates (not saying windows updates cause problems... just that problems almost always occur after updating)

Comment: What about `pub get`? What do you mean by `moved my entire project folder into it (dev tools)` What has you project folder to do with dev tools and what dev tool are you talking about anyway?

Comment: This may be very very late as I havent been back here in a while (tho I figured out what this problem is) without a fully installed and proper version of windows (updating libraries and security and whatnot) pub serve can fail to host...